# TypeScript: "extends" string literal type check not working

Tags: typescript

When trying to type check the dependency between keys and values in an object, I try to define `MyObject` as:

```
type Key =  AKey| BKey
type AKey = `A${string}`
type BKey = `B${string}`
type Item<Key> = 
   Key extends AKey ? {a:string} : 
   Key extends BKey ? {b:number} : 
   {}
type MyObject = {[key:Key]:Item<Key>}
```

There is no error, however invalid inputs are accepted without errors:

```
let test1:MyObject = {"Afoo":{a:"yes"}}
let test2:MyObject = {"Afoo":{b:1}} // should fail
let test3:MyObject = {"Bbar":{a:"no"}} // should fail
let test4:MyObject = {"Bbar":{b:2}}
```

It looks like `extends` is not working with string literal types or is it something else?

I know about `as const` for a closed set of keys but this doesn't apply here as I need the keys set to be infinite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it written now `MyObject` results in:

```
{
    [key: `A${string}`]: { a: string } |  { b: number };
    [key: `B${string}`]: { a: string } |  { b: number };
}
```

That's because union `AKey| BKey` is passed to `Item<Key>`. But we want to resolve the value for each key separately. This can be achieved using [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html):

```
type MyObject = { [K in Key]: Item<K> }

let test1: MyObject = { "Afoo": { a: "yes" } }
let test2: MyObject = { "Afoo": { b: 1 } } // now fails
let test3: MyObject = { "Bbar": { a: "no" } } // now fails
let test4: MyObject = { "Bbar": { b: 2 } }
```

Now `MyObject` is resolved to:

```
{
    [key: `A${string}`]: { a: string };
    [key: `B${string}`]: { b: number };
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hJQLxQIJwQHygIXQKFElXSSgAMUASAbwGdgAnASwDsBzAXzIPGl3lJlsNes3ZceRAJLAIAWwA86AHxI8UWAIgAPWSwAmtYgID8UalACGALiijWbKByjX1mhDr2GcJMxYBGtiwArnL%20EAxOLm7UHHiS0ACyIADy-gBWEADGwKQWANowUKzuALq2MvJKqnF4ADYQubL0AIy2yWmZOXlQAEQoAGYA9kO9thY2fSAQtL1RcQ1NM8AATO2pGdm5yBb9w6PjUIFQLfNQAPTnUAOWTHW09Y1QzcAAzOudWz292P6WDGNzFZbL0WKMzpdrrd7o8lvQACwfTbdHZ9X7-QEBWwreZAA)